# I want to get user current location in radians(instead of degrees) using python

Tags: python, location, latitude-longitude, haversine

I am using haversine library in python to get user location in radians.

I am using the haversine library in python which is giving me user's current location in degrees. But I want it in Radians.

```py
from haversine import haversine
haversine((33.3569,72.8307),(73.0472, 33.580), unit='km')
```

I also used the below code to convert it into radians but I'm not getting the right answer.

```py
haversine((math.radians(33.3569),math.radians(72.8307)),(math.radians(73.0472),  math.radians(33.5809)), unit='km')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to convert the coordinates from degrees to radians, you can use the math.radians() function from the Python math module.

Here's how you can use it in your code:

```
from haversine import haversine
import math

coord1 = (33.5648554, 73.0240976)
coord2 = (33.5802237, 73.0497602)

# Convert coordinates to radians
coord1_rad = (math.radians(coord1[0]), math.radians(coord1[1]))
coord2_rad = (math.radians(coord2[0]), math.radians(coord2[1]))

# Calculate distance using haversine function
distance = haversine(coord1_rad, coord2_rad, unit='km')

print(distance)
```

This should give you the distance between the two coordinates in kilometers.